# Bing search Link to underlying link in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, url, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

We get links like this:

```
http://www.bing.com/news/apiclick.aspx?ref=FexRss&aid=&tid=23A2D3B3B1FC42ADB33E0D6A07F0E740&url=https%3a%2f%2ftimesofindia.indiatimes.com%2fgadgets-news%2fwhatsapp-for-android-finally-gets-fingerprint-security%2farticleshow%2f71842024.cms&c=7798011707021326482&mkt=en-us
```

What formula can I use in Google Sheets to get the underlying link:

```
https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/gadgets-news/whatsapp-for-android-finally-gets-fingerprint-security/articleshow/71842024.cms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "bing.com(.+)"), "http[^&]+"), "%3a", ":"), "%2f", "/")
```

[image: 0]

---

and for array:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXEXTRACT(
 REGEXEXTRACT(A20:A21, "bing.com(.+)"), "http[^&]+"), "%3a", ":"), "%2f", "/")))
```